# How To Put Dot in Function

Tags: python

How To Create Function With Dot in its Name Like:

```
def Something.FunctionName():
print("Hello World!")
```

I Did Know How To Do it But I Forgot How To Do That.

Like in LUA:

```
Something = {}
function Something.TestFunction()
print("Hello World!")
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```py
class Something: PrintHello = staticmethod(lambda: print("Hello World!"))

Something.PrintHello()
```

Alternative, using `types.SimpleNamespace`:

```py
>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> Something = SimpleNamespace(PrintHello=lambda: print('Hello World!'))
>>> Something.PrintHello()
Hello World!
```

*"You can, but don't do"*

```py
locals()['Something.FunctionName'] = lambda: print("Hello World!")
locals()['Something.FunctionName']()
```